# Unplanned space between two divs which i don't know how to fix

Tags: html, web

In my website, there is a problem only for xl screens, in fact on my screen is not visible. In the first part of the website, there are two divs: on the left, there is an image and on the right there is a purple background with some text and information. The problem is that there shouldn't be space between the two divs, but in xl there is a white bar of space vertically. Is possible to fix it?
(The div on the left -the image- was originally img-fluid and there was no space, but when I changed the class as fullScreen -they have to be fullscreen- the space appeared.)

```
<div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-lg d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                <img src="sfondo_linee/linee_sfondobianco.svg" class="fullScreen" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg bg-lightpurple d-flex align-items-center vertical-container justify-content-center fullScreen ">
                <h2 class="mt-6 ml-6 mt-12 ml-12">contattami</h2>
                <p class="col-6 display-5 mt-5 ml-7 mb-5">Hai bisogno di un'informazione o vuoi commissionare un
                    progetto? Sono felice di aiutarti! Non esitare a contattarmi attraverso un'email o il box qui sotto. Rispondo entro qualche ora.</p>

                    
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to bootstrap css. I'm not an expert in bootstrap, but the quickest fix from what I can see is to get rid of the padding from the first div.

So change `<div class="col-lg d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">`
To `<div class="col-lg d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block" style="padding: 0">`

The "good" fix would be use a better bootstrap class for that div or write your own css class.

Comment: thank you! unfortunately is not working, I'm trying to solve it the other way you said.